# flutter desktop (window) request administrator on launch

Tags: flutter, window, desktop, administrator

I need to run a command line that required administrator privilege. I use Process class from dart.io file to run the command... but I don't want to always request administrator if I need to execute a command that required administrator. do you have anything about my problem?

Comment: [Please check this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123035/19876705)