# How to launch other app(go service) when flutter windows app start?

Tags: windows, flutter, desktop

I write a flutter windows app, I want to launch a golang service when flutter app start on windows, and how run flutter app on windows with admininstrator rights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting CmakeLists.txt in runner directory with below:

```sh
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${BINARY_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS    "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the `trustInfo` security in `runner.exe.mainifest` file to get administator rights.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
            <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
        </windowsSettings>
    </application>
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <!-- Windows 10 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />
            <!-- Windows 8 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />
            <!-- Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />
        </application>
    </compatibility>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

There are same errors when link;

```sh
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
LINK : fatal error LNK1327: run mt.exe Error during [D:\hosec\IPSec VPN Client\Windows\ipsec-windows-client-front\build\windows\runner\ipsec_windows_client_front.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

I think there are two ways to get administrator rights, one is setting in manifest like above description, the other is setting in `CmakeLists.txt`,

```sh
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS \
"/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" \
/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
```

But the second way does not get the administrator rights when launching
a flutter windows app.